# Trying to insert js code into moodle course page using block

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

I'm making a block on moodle course which one of its purposes is to display the number of times the student see an activity

I did is but with two problems,

the first: if the course made of sections each on a page, this js code worked on one page only, don't know why?

the second: this code doesn't do its job when using 'tiles course format' and enable javascript navigation

this code is inside the function `get_required_javascript()`

```
$code = 'document.getElementById("module-'.$cmid.'")
     .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "' . addslashes_js($blockdata->viewstemplate) . '");';
$this->page->requires->js_amd_inline ($code);
// $this->page->requires->js_init_code($code , true);
```

I did try both funtions `js_amd_inline`  and `js_init_code`

EDIT

I changed the code to

```
$code = 'require(["jquery", "core/ajax"], function($, ajax) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var module = $("#module-'.$cmid.'");
        module.append("'.addslashes_js($blockdata->viewstemplate).'");
    });
    });';

$this->page->requires->js_init_code($code , true);
```

it solved the first problem, the second still exist

Answer (score 0):

I did that which solved the two problems but some time it doing it twice

```
        $code = 'require(["jquery", "core/ajax"], function($, ajax) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var module = $("#module-'.$cmid.'");
                module.append("'.addslashes_js($blockdata->viewstemplate).'");
              });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
                if (typeof (settings.data) !== \'undefined\') {
                    var data = JSON.parse(settings.data);
                    if (data.length > 0 && typeof (data[0].methodname) !== \'undefined\') {
                        if (data[0].methodname == \'format_tiles_get_single_section_page_html\' // Tile load.
                            || data[0].methodname == \'format_tiles_log_tile_click\') { // Tile load, cached.
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    var module = $("#module-'.$cmid.'");
                                    module.append("'.addslashes_js($blockdata->viewstemplate).'");
                                  });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
          });';
        $this->page->requires->js_init_code($code);
```